# Generic where on different children properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

I have mainEntity (Maintable) with many connected children entities(tables/many to many, one to many) but all children entities have a code property. I want to create a generic Where we I can ask which children that matches a list code property. Example

```
private IQueryable<MainTable> OneLevelSearch<T>(Func<T, string> datafunc, List< string>> codeList, IQueryable<MainTable> efQuerable)
        {
            if (codeList?.Count > 0)
            {
                List<string> distinctCodeList = codeList.Distinct().ToList();
                return efQuerable.Include(typeof(T).Name).Where(q => distinctCodeList.Contains(datafunc(d)));
            }

            return efQuerable;
        }
```

And then be able to call it like..

```
efQuerable= OneLevelSearch<ChildEntity>(d=>d.ChildEntity.Code,CodeList,efQuerable);
```

But since its a childproperty I havent made it right. What do I miss?

Comment: LINQ operators are already generic and EF Core deals with *entities*, not tables.  EF Core 5 introduced [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) which is the only way to load only specific related (not child) entities.The correct syntax is eg `query.Include(x=>x.Somethings.Where(s=>somethings.Contains(s.Code)))`

Comment: Furthermore, LINQ works with `Expression`s not `Func`s. The expressions will be translated to SQL, not executed. Building an expression can be tricky so you should consider using [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to create expressions